# Can Wordpress Duplicate An Entire Page Structure?

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I have a wordpress site that i've been working on that has some pages (as in NOT posts) that a client changes content on in order to target particular keywords. these pages have been using podscms for content management.

The client now wants to be able to duplicate these pages any number of times and edit the text within them. So basically, he wants to be have a dozen or so versions of about 4 linked pages.

Does anyone know if it's possible to duplicate an entire multipage structure like this in WP?

Or any WP driven sites that implement segmentation similarly?

Comment: You want to put the same content on more than one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates).  You define them in the theme and then for each Wordpress page you create, you can select which page template you would like to use for the page.  This sounds like what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: pages were the way to go - don't ask me why i didn't think of that before =( i was too concerned with the client wanting to replicate the structure at the push of a button. i just went ahead and provided page templates with custom fields. thanks!